# how to disable the future time in Datetimepicker when i have already disabled the future dates

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

```
var FromEndDate = new Date();
     $('.conv_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        endDate: FromEndDate,
        autoclose: true
    });
```

Comment: here is the code of how am disabling the future dates..but when i do changes in the time like i go back or increase the time then it is accepting the future next day time that means it should not accept the future date both through the calender and through the timepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, if you are using the Bootstrap DateTimePicker from http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/  :

```
function ValidateConvTime() {
    var eventTime = $("#conv_datetimepicker").data('DateTimePicker').date();
    var currentTime = new Date();

    if (eventTime > currentTime) {
        alert("error")
    }       
}
```